# Function to check on variables that may or may not exist - PHP

Tags: php

I have a function that is meant to check if two variables match, but with different values. It's a kinda complicated idea... but here's an example of its usage:

```
match($set1->test,"YES",$set2->test,"ON")
```

It will return true if `$set1->test == "YES" && $set2->test == "ON"`

Here's an example of how its implemented:

```
function match($field1,$val1,$field2,$val2) {
    if ((isset($field1) && $field1 == $val1) && (isset($field2) && $field2 == $val2)) 
    {
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

So the big issue here is you CANNOT do `isset` inside a function with the function's arguments. It's pointless, because the error gets thrown that `$set1->test` does not exist when the function is called, and if it isn't an object property then the variable gets initialized in the function scope anyway. It seems that the only way to get around this is to do the isset test on `$set1->test` and `$set2->test` before passing them to the function, but I really don't want to. It feels unnecessary.

My question is how can I call `match($set1->test,"YES",$set2->test,"ON")` when `$set1->test` or `$set2->test` has not been set?

---

**ANSWER**

I'm going to use a variation on Tamás's answer. I will have a separate function called `prop`, like this:

```
function prop($obj, $property) {
  if (property_exists($obj,$property)) {
    return $obj->$property;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Then I'll call `match` like this:

`match(prop($set1,'test'),"YES",prop($set2,'test'),"ON")`

Thanks!

Comment: Why wouldnt you just declare them as a default state of null and then check to see if they are null or not? 

function match($field1=null,$val1=null,$field2=null,$val2=null) {

Comment: @Epik, this is not about default values, but about using variables as function call parameters that might or might not be set.

Comment: Why would you want to call match if it's not been set? There's no reason to call match if their value hasn't been set, is there?

Comment: You could go for variable variables … if you want an ugly solution to an ugly problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using property_exists

```
function match($obj1, $obj2,$property,$val1,$val2) {
    if ((property_exists($obj1, $property) && $obj1->$property == $val1) && (property_exists($obj2, $property) && $obj2->$property == $val2)) 
    {
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very popular, but this could be a valid use for the `@` modifier to disable errors:

```
@match($set1->test, "YES", $set2->test, "ON");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
function match($field1=NULL,$val1=NULL,$field2=NULL,$val2=NULL) {
    $result = false;
    if (!is_null($field) && !is_null($val1) && !is_null($field2) && !is_null($val2)) {
            if ($field1 == $val1 && $field2 == $val2) {
                $result = true;
            }
            else {
                $result = false;    
            }  
    } 
    return $result;
}
```